# deploying asp.net MVC 1.0 app with HTTPS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, https, web-deployment-project

We have an application built on ASP.NET MVC 1.0 which, once deployed, should be accessed with HTTPS. I tried few approaches for HTTPS but I have a few questions.:

1. My home page does not need to be Secured (HTTPS), but rest of the hyperlinks following it will be Secured.
2. I read about the action method attribute [requiresHTTPS] however I want to understand what happens to that tag during development on local machine.
3. In a development enviroment, how do I install a certificate on a dev machine/virtual directory to code and test my changes.

---

### So this application is complex in nature and we have around 13 controllers and 50 action methods. This application will have information like Credit card numbers since we do accept payment through this website.

Thanks much !

Answer (score 0):

If it is just about a few static pages of your application that don't need to be secured, I would strongly recommend to simply require SSL for *everything* by configuring two different sites in IIS, one for the actual page only on port 443, one on port 80 with a permanent redirect.

Advantages:

- Your application and code doesn't have to know anything about SSL, and you don't need a SSL certificate on your dev machine. The web server does it all for you.
- No cookie and HTTP caching mess with the HTTP/HTTPS flip-flop
- If security/privacy matters, it's the best solution anyway to require SSL for all pages.

Regarding the possible disadvantage: serving a few requests on static resources via SSL is probably almost no overhead, compared to the rest of your application.

Comment: I just updated the information on my question. Please suggest me now on the approach.

Comment: I guess my suggestion is still valid. Actually the question is: why would people want to run only parts of their web sites via HTTPS and the rest without? That's because SSL adds a little CPU overhead to every request. This was significant 10 years ago, and today, if you need 50 machines running your applications you could maybe save 5% of them if you use HTTPS only on selected pages, but honestly, most of the webservers out there are idle anyway most of the time, and the bottleneck for the typical web server today is not CPU, but memory and I/O in case of the database.

Comment: Well we only have 1 (home page) which need not be secured. Rest all of them are sercured and this recomendation is from the client. Now they also dont want another virtual directory to be created for single page.